# Disabled text box is not submitted with the form MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, html, forms, model-view-controller

I have a textbox which is having a property "disabled".
But when I submit the form, the textbox name/value is not sent to the controller.

Comment: Have you tried changing it to not be disabled and then submit to see if that works?

Comment: Disable text box value will not sent in form change it to read only

Answer (score 2):

Input fields marked with `disabled` never send their value to the server when the form is posted.

You could use the `readonly` attribute in order to send to server and not editable by user.

Answer (score 2):

Input fields with disabled attribute does not send their value to the controller while submitting the form. You can use one of below solution to overcome the issue

1) You can use **readonly** attribute instead of **disabled** attribute to send data to controller

2) You can add **hidden field** for each of fields with **disabled** attribute to send data to controller